# pandas to_json returns a string not a json object

Tags: javascript, python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am using the following python code to return a json object:

```
df_as_json = df.to_json(orient='split')
return jsonify({'status': 'ok', 'json_data': df_as_json})
```

When I read the object back in javascript:

```
// response is xhr respose from server
const mydata = response.data
console.log(mydata.constructor.name)
// >Obj
const dfdata = mydata.json_data
console.log(dfdata.constructor.name)
// >String
```

Is there a way to send the df_as_json as a json object inside the parent response.data json object?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "json object" in python that's why`.to_json` returns a string representation of the json object, json in python is essentially the same as a `dict`, you can use the `to_dict` method instead.

```
df_as_json = df.to_dict(orient='split')
return jsonify({'status': 'ok', 'json_data': df_as_json})
```

Comment: JSON _is_ a string!  It's used to represent objects.  You may even say it's an Object Notation, inspired by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Just return dict and let jsonify convert dict to string.

```
df_as_json = df.to_dict()
return jsonify({'status': 'ok', 'json_data': df_as_json})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json in python directly.

```
# some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)
return y

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"])
```