# Fix a JSON.parse Syntax Error for a Python Flask App

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

I'm trying to work with some JSON data into my JavaScript using JSON.parse in my Flask app. However, I'm getting the following error.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 3`

I'm suspecting it may be something to do with the quotes, but am not sure. Code is below.

**Python (app.y)**

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template
import json

test_data = [['mack', 10, 988], ['john', 15, 200], ['jane', 14, 590]]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Score'])
json_df = test_df.set_index('Name').to_json(orient='index')
    
@app.route("/hello")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", json_df=json_df)
```

**JavaScript** (within my index.html file)

```
<script>
    const json_df = JSON.parse('{{ json_df|tojson }}');
    console.log(json_df);
</script>
```

Basically, I want to be able to work with the data in JavaScript, such that:

```
const json_df = {mack:{Age:10,Score:988},john:{Age:15,Score:200},jane:{Age:14,Score:590}}
```

Comment: you should use dict instead of json. or first load index page then call json from another route.

Comment: You don't need to parse the JSON. JSON is literally valid Javascript. You don't need to package it in a string that needs to be parsed. `json_df` also already is JSON. Just do `const df = {{ json_df }};`.

Comment: @deceze when you take the JSON directly without parsing, it remains in this notation, and I can't pull directly by the key (e.g., with json_df.mack)

Comment: Your Python `json_df` is a string like `'{"mack": ...}'`. When you put this into a template with `const df = {{ json_df }};`, the result will be `const df = {"mack": ...};`. This is now already a fully valid Javascript object.

Comment: Thanks. If I may clarify something quickly though: if I try this `var json_df = '{"john":{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}}'; console.log(json_df.john.name)` it doesn't work, but if I put JSON.parse, it does work?

Comment: If your JS code looks like `var json_df = '...';`, then it's a string and not an object. If your JS code looks like `var df = {...};`, then it's an object.

Comment: A million thanks @deceze! That thinking helped me to find the root of the issue. I managed to fix it in the earlier part of the python code now, using `to_dict` instead, following your advice and this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614102/pandas-to-json-returns-a-string-not-a-json-object